# Ag-Grid : How to get the value of the cell on clicking the cell

Tags: angular, ag-grid

how can I get the value of the cell when the cell is clicked clicked in Angular?

this is my HTML :

```html
    <ag-grid-angular  
    style="width: 100%; height: 300px;" 
    class="ag-theme-alpine"
    [rowData]="list" 
    [columnDefs]="columnDefs"
    [defaultColDef]="defaultColDef"
    [pagination]="true"
    [modules]="modules"
    >
    </ag-grid-angular>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Listen to cellClicked event https://www.ag-grid.com/angular-data-grid/grid-events/

```html
<ag-grid-angular  
style="width: 100%; height: 300px;" 
class="ag-theme-alpine"
[rowData]="list" 
[columnDefs]="columnDefs"
[defaultColDef]="defaultColDef"
[pagination]="true"
[modules]="modules"
(cellClicked)="onCellClicked($event)"
>
</ag-grid-angular>
```

```js
onCellClicked(cellData){
  console.log(cellData.value)
}
```